# useHash for all but a single component

Tags: angular, adal.js

I am using Angular 6 with ADAL.js. At login users are redirected to Azure Active Directory, and following to a redirect url http://localhost:4200/authcallback. However when I started using useHash:true, the redirect was broken. I tried adding following redirect uri into AAD:

http://localhost:4200/#/authcallback

But AAD can't apperently handle this. Is there away to say useHash:true for everything but a single route?

Comment: Dont use hash at all. Why do you need it ?

Comment: I just realized your right. It was because I wanted to deep linking but I realized it didnt work because I havent set my baseUrl